# Yodlee api rest searchSite

Tags: yodlee

The Yodlee POST request "/jsonsdk/SiteTraversal/searchSite" requires three parameters:

1. cobSessionToken - Understandable.
2. siteSearchString - Understandable.
3. userSessionToken - Does this imply that there is a unique list per user and I cannot/may not "cache" a generic list of sites to present to users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cache a generic list of sites to present to users, and users can search out of that list. Though, there can be a case where your cached list is old and may not have any newly added sites and user might be searching for that bank.

It is recommended to use this if you are not updating your cached list once per day.